# How to override protected function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides, items, data

I'm trying to override one protected function in Magento 2 but I am not able to achieve it. I have edited following files:

```
  <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="XYZ\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />

    <?php

    namespace XYZ\Checkout\CustomerData;

    class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
    {
```

but still not working